# Generating HTML in Rails Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, architecture, rubygems

I'm working on a project with Events which are published to EventBrite. An Event has a number of fields (Bio, Image, etc...) which will published to EventBrite as a HTML blob. It feels dirty to generate HTML straight from the model and I think that I'd rather see something like how mailers are done, but it feels like I'm reinventing the wheel.

Any recommendations?

Comment: erb/haml provide templating but don't solve the issue that the Event model is being wired to a view.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

An example is described [in this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper).

---

```
# @param view_name [String]
# @param locals [Hash] containing the variables you want to pass to the view (I guess only the decorator itself)
def render(view_name, locals = {})
  filename = File.join "app", "views", "decorators", "#{view_name}.html.erb"
  template = File.read filename
  eruby = Erubis::Eruby.new(template)
  eruby.result locals
end
```

Comment: +1 definitely agree. You've come across one of the flaws on MVC

Comment: @sethvargo: fully agreed to your comment

Comment: With Draper, its wouldn't it still be a case of the Model generating the view?

Comment: Not directly, but you could create your own method which will get an erb file in a dedicated folder and pass the variables to it. Would you like an example?

Comment: Thanks @apneadiving. erb examples are fairly abundant so I'm all set. I guess what I am trying to really figure out is whether its worth it to create something like a EventBriteDispatcher with a method that would take an Event and call to EventBrite.

Comment: can't really answer your architecture question :)